# How to Maximize a opened application window in task-bar and minimize it using python?

Tags: python-2.7

How to maximize a application window exists in task-bar and again have to minimize using python.
For Example: I have already opened calculator application and that is already existed on task-bar and want to maximize the calculator and have to minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be interesting for you https://pywinauto.github.io/ if, of course, you are a windows user.